# syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting '('

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code is

```
 for i in 0..array_dif.count-1
   a = array_dif[i] - array_dif[0]
   b = array_dif[array_dif.count-1] - array_dif[0]
   norm = a.0/b
   array_norm[i] = norm
 end
```

And i'm getting the following error:

```
rb:135: no .<digit> floating literal anymore; put 0 before dot (SyntaxError)
    norm = a.0/b
             ^
C:/piegas/config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb:135: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting '('
    norm = a.0/b
              ^
```

I don't know whats wrong with it

Answer (score 1):

`norm = a.0/b` is an invalid statement (aka SyntaxError).

What do you want that statement to do?

`norm = a/b` might make sense.

`norm = array_dif[0]/b` might also make sense.

But without knowing the purpose of the code, it's difficult to know what the correct solution is.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by `a.0/b`? It is invalid. If you were trying to convert a to float then it would be `a.to_f/b`.

Comment: Yes, i was trying to convert "a" to float! Thank you. First time programming in ruby haha